# Should I use neo4j when want to save d3 force graph for next time rendering?

Tags: mongodb, graph, neo4j, d3-force-directed

It seems that if I want to render d3 force-directed graph with nodes and links, links pass to the simulation must be in a list of 2-tuple.

This means I need to export the neo4j "connection" back to a list of 2-tuple if I want to render it again next time.

Then, in this case, I couldn't get any benefit from the "native" graph database(quick).

Should I then just probably store the  2-tuple list in MongoDB instead? then I could save time "export the neo4j connection to a list of 2-tuple".

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for using a native graph database is hardly ever pure visualization. But yes, your d3 or any other library you will use , will expect a list of nodes and edges. There are many tools , including ours (Graphileon) that do that conversion of a set of nodes/edges or entire paths for you.

disclosure:I work for graphileon

Comment: Should I then just probably store the 2-tuple list in MongoDB instead? then I could save time "export the neo4j connection to a list of 2-tuple"

Comment: Hard to say, without knowing more about the use case. But given the fact that you want to visualise data as a graph, it is probably about “connections” in some shape or form. Which would make it worth while to properly look into advantages of using graph technology (besides the viz aspect) in your case.